# Vim, put off indent in global config

Tags: vim, vimrc

My vim have a auto indent future for C files. I can run it and `:set nocindent` to change this behaviour. I don’t know what to add to the global configuration file. I’ve tested these lines without effects.

```
set nocindent
set noautoindent
set nosmartindent
filetype indent off
filetype plugin indent off
```

I’m out of ideas. My vim version is 8.0.13 .

Comment: Have you tried to add these settings to `/etc/vim/vimrc.local`?

Comment: I don’t have any `/etc/vim/vimrc.local` but `/etc/vimrc`.

Comment: You have to create `/etc/vim/vimrc.local` yourself.

Comment: I created but it didn't work.

Comment: Well, I have to admit that I just traced vim to see which config files it read. Run these two commands `strace -o vim.log -eopen vim foo` exit vim and run `grep "/etc/" vim.log` then you will see the files read from `/etc/`.

Comment: I’ve run this strace, but I have only `/etc/vimrc`.

Answer (score 0):

Syntax and filetype plugins are able to override your default settings. The reason for this is that they are applied later, when the file is opened, as opposed to when vim starts.

To work around this, you can do something like:

```
autocmd FileType * set nocindent
```

Basically this results in calling `set nocindent` every time a file is opened.

Change the `*` to `c` if you only want this to apply to `c` files.

Comment: Doesn’t work for me.

Answer (score 0):

@Michas: As far as I know, we can re-define our Vim's environment using the "-u" option inline with the vim command. For example:

1) Creating a file, say ~/.yourvim, with the following stuffs:

```
set nocindent
set noautoindent
```

2) Then add into your ~/.bashrc file this line

```
alias vim="vim -u ~/.yourvim"
```

3) Exit the current terminal, open a new one and you can try with the new vim's environment.

I am using this trick to define my own vim. Of course we can provide more options inside the "~/.yourvim" files as well as the "alias" command. So far, it works on my Debian 8 with vim version 7.4.

There is another way: modify or create (if it does not exists)

```
~/.vimrc
```

put the following lines into the latter file

```
set nocindent
set noautoindent
```

Exit the current terminal, open a new one and try. Good luck!

Comment: This hack is too complicated. The vim is too critical.